# showing last 4 digits of stripe credit card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to figure out how to show the last 4 digits of the users default card on file with Stripe. The code I came up with does not display it.

Does anyone have a idea of how to fix what I have?

controller:

```
  def last4
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
  card = customer.cards.retrieve(user.subscription.stripe_card_id)
  charge = Stripe::Charge.retrieve(user.subscription.stripe_charge_id)
  self.last_4_digits = charge.card.last4
  end
```

Comment: Just use the returned card. Not the card off of the charge.

Comment: Also if you store the customer_token locally which you have to. You can also store the last 4 safely.

Comment: If it's a string, you can just write charge.card[-4..-1]

Comment: Is there even a 'default' card, or is it just a list of stored cards? When I've done something like this, I've just returned a list of the cards and let them choose which one to check out with. I believe you'd have to have a column that stores the card identifier or last 4.

Answer (score 5):

the stripe customer will have a `default_source` field which will give you the card id. Search the cards in sources attribute with the card id to get the card object, which will give you the `last4` attribute.

```
@stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("stripe customer id")
default_card_id = @stripe_customer.default_source
@default_card = @stripe_customer.sources[:data].find {|x| x[:id] == default_card_id }
@default_card.last4
```